# Выбрать третий одинаковый элемент

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть три выпадающих списка, мне нужно добраться до третьего, можно ли как то пропускать элементы при поиске?

Comment: Используй xpath, и передавай индекс того элемента, на котором хочешь сделать действия

Comment: Или же через driver.findElements() найти все похожие элементы и выбать из них нужные тебе по индексу

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[3]"));
```